# How do you convert an InputStream to a base64 string in Scala?

Tags: scala

Trying to pull an image off of Amazon S3 (returns `S3ObjectInputStream`) and send it to the [mandrill email api](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html#method=send) (takes a base64-encoded string).  How can this be done in Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one solution, there are probably others more efficient.

```
val is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Array[Byte](1, 2, 3)) // replace by your InputStream
val stream = Stream.continually(is.read).takeWhile(_ != -1).map(_.toByte)
val bytes = stream.toArray
val b64 = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(bytes)
```

You could (and should) also replace the `sun.misc` encoder by the apache commons [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) for a better compatibility.

```
val b64 = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(bytes)
```

Answer (score 13):

I also managed to do it just using the Apache commons; not sure which approach is better, but figured I'd leave this answer for the record:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

val bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream)
val bytes64 = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes)
val content = new String(bytes64)
```

Comment: I think your answer is better, supposing the apache commons library is available.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [simple encoder/decoder](https://github.com/marklister/base64) I wrote that you can include as source.  So, no external dependencies.

The interface is a bit more scala-esque:

`import io.github.marklister.base64.Base64._
// Same as Lomig Mégard's answer
val b64 = bytes.toBase64`